# PowerShell "F1" doesn't show any useful about_* topics after updating it properly

Tags: powershell, help-files

When I installed Win10, I brought over a PowerShell profile that I'd maintained since the days of PowerShell beta that still had some old modules in it that no longer work. Nothing particularly terrible happens except that Get-Help doesn't like me much: many topics end up giving me weird errors, just like [this presumably fixed-in-Insider UserVoice](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/11679417-get-help-cmdlet-fails-to-show-about-topics-when-in). I renamed the Modules subfolder with the problematic modules to something else, restarted PS, and tried updating help again with `-Force`, but while I didn't get any errors, I still can't get `Get-Help about_*` to show me any of the standard topics. I can see PSCX help (which is a functional module as far as I can tell, and was installed via Chocolatey after the migration anyway), but nothing else.

How do I get PowerShell help to include the standard meta topics? Is there a particular module I should specify for `Update-Help` to work on? `Save-Help` somehow, maybe?